# Как добавить сообщение человека в переменную?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```html
import telebot
import CONFIG
import wikipedia

bot = telebot.TeleBot(CONFIG.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def wiki(message):
    request = message.from_user
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот что мне удалось найти', wikipedia.summary(request))


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Вам `message.text` нужен?

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить в переменную текст, отправленный человеком.

Answer (score 0):

Текст, отправленный пользователем, можно получить из этого значения `message.text`
То есть, что бы объявить переменную пишете:

```
usertext = message.text
```

`usertext` есть название переменной

Если помог, сообщите, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!)))

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def wiki(message):
    request = message.text   # сообщение от пользователя сохраняется в message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот что мне удалось найти', wikipedia.summary(request))
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)))